# How to reproject data in EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 using SharpMapv0.9 for display on Google Maps

Tags: sql-server, coordinate-system, sharpmap

I have data stored in `SQL Server 2012` in **EPSG:4326**. I need to display this data on a Google Map in **EPSG:3857**, but without an `ST_Transform` function, I cannot determine how to convert my data on the fly to **EPSG:3857** to display them properly.

Answer (score 1):

turned out it was easier to load the data into SpatialLite, transform to 3857 and then transfer to SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Is it the correct app? https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/

Answer (score -2):

After weeks of trying to solve this same problem, this amazing set of code samples absolutely saved me:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#Spherical_Mercator